# Basic variance question

Tags: variance

$\newcommand\E{\mathbb E}$Suppose we toss a coin $n$ times, and let the r.v. $X$ denote the number of heads we see.  Moreover, let $X_{i} = 1$ if the $i$-th toss is a heads, otherwise $0$.

$$\mathrm{Var}(X) = \E(X^{2}) - (\E(X))^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(X_{i} = 1)(1^{2}) - \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{2} = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{n^{2}}{4}$$

Thus, if $n=100$, this would mean the variance is $50 - 2500 = -2450$...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\E{\mathbb E}$This "equality":
$$
\E(X^2)\ ``="\sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(X_i = 1) (1^2)
$$
is not correct. That's saying
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^2\ ``=" \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2
,$$
when it should actually be
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 + \sum_{i \ne j} a_i a_j
.$$

The correct version is then
\begin{align}
\E(X^2)
&= \E \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 + \sum_{i \ne j} X_i X_j \right)
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \E\left[ X_i^2 \right] + \sum_{i \ne j} \E\left[ X_i X_j \right]
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \Pr\left(X_i = 0 \right) 0^2 + \Pr\left( X_i = 1 \right) 1^2 \right) + \sum_{i \ne j} \E\left[ X_i \right] \E\left[ X_j \right]
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac12
   + \sum_{i \ne j} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}
\\&= \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{4} n (n-1)
\\&= \frac14 n^2 + \frac14 n
,\end{align}
so that
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)
= \frac14 n^2 + \frac14 n - \frac14 n^2
= \frac{n}{4}
.$$